# iOS contact application

Tags: ios

Iam trying to create a contact application exactly like the one in iphone.
I have an add button in my  FirstView on the click of that it will presentmodal  to  "NewContact" view
when we click done it will create a plist and write all the values to plist and then dismiss the view back to firstView. Iam finding it difficult to show the name in the firstView.

My first view:

```
-(void)btnrightClicked:(id)sender
{
    NewContactViewController *newContact= [[NewContactViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewContactViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:newContact animated:YES];  
}
```

My 3rd view:

```
-(IBAction)btnDoneClicked:(id) sender
{       
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Details.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL success = [fm fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Details" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fm copyItemAtPath:path toPath:filePath error:nil];
    }

    NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

if ([txtfirst.text length] > 0) 
{
    [dict setObject:txtfirst.text forKey:@"first"];
}
else {
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Dont leave name blank" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}



if ([txtlast.text length] > 0) 
{
    [dict setObject:txtlast.text forKey:@"last"];
}


if ([txtwork.text length] > 0) 
{
    [dict setObject:txtwork.text forKey:@"work"];
}


if ([txtnumber1.text length] > 0) 
{
    [dict setObject:txtnumber1.text forKey:@"number1"];
}
else {
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Dont leave number blank" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}


if ([txtnumber2.text length] > 0) 
{
    [dict setObject:txtnumber2.text forKey:@"number2"];
}

if ([txtringtone.text length] > 0) 
{
    [dict setObject:txtringtone.text forKey:@"ringtone"];
}

if ([txtemailid1.text length] > 0) 
{
    [dict setObject:txtemailid1.text forKey:@"emailid1"];
}

if ([txtemailid2.text length] > 0) 
{
    [dict setObject:txtemailid2.text forKey:@"emailid2"];
}



[contacts addObject:dict];
[contacts writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
[dict release];

{
    if ([txtfirst.text length] > 0 && [txtnumber1.text length] > 0) {
        alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:(txtfirst.text) message:@"Your details saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
    [self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Did the ViewTransitions example solve the issue. Here is the link- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: You'll have to provide more information. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: What's the point of creating a contact application **exactly** like the one on iPhone? It won't get on the store.

Comment: thanks caleb please see the iphone contacts application in simulator.in the NEWCONTACTS view iam entering name,number etc on clicking done button it will get stored in plist and dismiss view to ALLCONTACTS there i have to show the name which i have entered in the NEWCONTACTS just like in iphone simulator

Comment: @Abizern its a task friend :)

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is creating a delegate protocol in your first view conroller and have your second view controller implement the protocol method that updates the data in the first view controller when you go back down the stack.

I made a [simple demonstration project](http://goo.gl/y22Tf) that you can download and have a look at to see what I mean.

Comment: thanks for the sample code..can u suggest how to use delegate in my code ??

Comment: I've given you an entire example - what specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: iam not able to get values from plist and  automatically updated them to tableview in firstview

Comment: am trying to bring the firstnames to cells of uitableview in the parentview .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Core Data, which solves the issue of notifying or delegating any data to super. The view controller with all the contacts will update automatically when you've created a contact.

Comment: You could, but it would be advisable to use Core Data if this is the case.